# iPhone X screenEdgePanGesture not working (swift)?

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, iphone-x

I'm running some regular edgePan code to initialise edgePan detection:

```
func setupGestures() {
    let edgePan = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(screenEdgeSwiped))
    edgePan.edges = .left
    edgePan.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(edgePan)
}
```

and the selector:

```
func screenEdgeSwiped(recognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .recognized {
        if slideOutMenuView != nil {
            slideOutMenuView.show()
        }
        else {
            print("THE SLIDE OUT MENU VIEW IS NIL")
        }
    }
}
```

This all works fine but when I give it a test run on the iPhone X. It seems to not even register the gesture.
Is there a different screenGesture that they have introduced or have they completely overwritten the functionality?

The App is in landscape mode.

Comment: your code work's fine.

Comment: @Jack did you test it on an iPhone X?
Maybe I'm doing something else wrong, the app doesn't appear to fill to the edge of the screen as well. It could be the setting of view sizes.
But I have put prints and breakpoints in the code for the selector and it's never reached.

Comment: Which xcode & swift version you are using?

Comment: @Jack Xcode 8.3 | swift 3

Comment: Are you using other gestures on same controller?

Comment: @Jack there is a touch/tap gesture recogniser as well.
On a different device with the same code, it functions as expected.